# Collect data from PHP form and save it to HTML file?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am looking into how to store PHP data to an HTML file. Basically what I want to do is take the data and immediately publish it to a separate HTML file that is automatically visible without the need to use MySQL. I would also want to record multiple submissions to the same HTML file without overwriting. Here is the data form created using the `<form>` variable:

```
  <form action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="location">Please Describe Your Location</label>
    <textarea id="location" name="location" placeholder="Describe your location..." style="height:200px"></textarea>
    
    <label for="issue">Please Describe The Issue</label>
    <textarea id="issue" name="issue" placeholder="Describe the issue..." style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <center>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </center>
    
  </form>
```

Basically, I'd want this to be sent to an html file and have it updated live with every new form submission without overwriting previous submissions. The data is printed for the user who submitted the form by the `action_page.php` which looks like:

```
<b>Name: </b> <?php echo $_GET['firstname']; $_GET["lastname"]; ?><br>
<b>Location: </b> <?php echo $_GET['location']; ?><br>
<b>Issue: </b> <?php echo $_GET['issue']; ?><br>
<b>Date: </b><?php echo date("Y/m/d") . "<br>"; ?>
<b>Time Submitted: </b><?php echo date("h:i:sa"); ?>
```

Is this possible, or would I have to use MySQL?

Comment: use fopen() in append mode, then use fwrite()

Comment: This will probably give you headaches. Use a database like everyone else. Maybe even better, use an existing CMS rather than re-inventing (half) the wheel :-)

Comment: Hello-- if you found my answer helpful (below) please mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First things first: there are SERIOUS** security concerns here.  But just for the sake of education, here's what I would do:

Your output should be a string.  Ex:

```
$html .= "First Name: " . $_GET['first_name'] . "<br>";
$html .= "Last Name: " . $_GET['last_name'] . "<br>";
```

And so on.

Then you can just use PHP's handy file_put_contents() function like so:

```
file_put_contents("myfile.html", $html);
```

To make it always append (if the files exists already), use a flag/constant:

```
file_put_contents("myfile.html", $html, FILE_APPEND);
```

** As for the security concerns: you should NEVER allow an Internet user to write to files on your system without sanitizing the input, as well as other checks.  For example, a malicious user could write a script to write millions of submissions per minute to your script and end up filling your hard drive up and bringing down the server. Or, they could inject malicious javascript or even PHP onto your file system. **So, use this answer very carefullY!**